# Determine matrix boundary without loops

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have got a 2D matrix. There is some region in the matrix where the elements are non-zero, in particular everywhere around the edge they are zero.

I plot the matrix using image as a colorplot and would like to add the curve that shows the boundary between non-zero values to zero values in the matrix. Is there any neat way to do this without loops?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a job for [`convhull`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhull.html?refresh=true) :

To illustrate this code i'll take a dummy example :

```
A=zeros(10);
B=binornd(1,0.5,8,8);
A(2:end-1,2:end-1)=B

A =

 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
 0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     0
 0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0
 0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
 0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
 0     0     1     0     1     1     1     1     0     0
 0     1     0     1     1     1     1     0     1     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

**1/ Find the locations of all non zero entries :**

```
[row,col]=find(A);
```

**2/ Take the convex hull of these locations**

```
k=convhull(row,col);
```

**3/ Plot the convex hull** (I plot the non zero points aswell but in your problem it will be your image points)

```
plot(row(k),col(k),'r-',row,col,'b*')
```

**Result :**

[image]

Comment: Nice way of solving the problem!

Comment: @BillBokeey: thanks for your answer mate! I had some trouble with inputting the correctly transposed matrix initially, but after overcoming that your solution worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using the image processing toolbox and the [`bwperim`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwperim.html) function. This will work if you know that your area is completely closed (i.e. has no holes in the boundary)

This is an example using a black and white image, and you have 2 options: fill the inner gaps before, or not. You can see in the result the differences.

```
A = imread('circles.png');

Afill=imfill(A,'holes'); % optional
Abound1=bwperim(Afill);
Abound2=bwperim(A);
imshow([A,Abound, Abound2])
```

[image]

You can plot one on top of the other with:

```
[x,y]= find(Abound2);
hold on
image(A*255)  %// If A is logical, else use just A (not *255)
colormap('gray')
plot(y,x,'r.')
hold off
axis tight
```

[image]

If you have a gray-scale image (or a matrix with a single value in each position (2D matrix), then you can binarize it first by either:

1. If you know everything outside your object is EXACTLY zero 
   `A=yourA>0;`
2. If you want to separate your object from the background, and the background is not exactly zero by `A=im2bw(yourA,level)`, by choosing your own level, or letting Otsu do it for you with `level=graythresh(yourA)`